# Bird Animation customization

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, boids

I am trying to create a website. The link for the website is:

http://www.eclectika.org/test3

I want the birds in the following link:

http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/canvas_geometry_birds.html

to be in my background. Please someone suggest me the way. I have tried many things. Still cant get it right.

Also please suggest a way to change the color of the birds.

Comment: I suggest learning how Three.js works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learning three.js will defiantly helps.

The `Renderer` function just creates a new DOM element and draws the `Scene` on it.

So the easiest way you can achieve your goal is that you set the `z-index` css property of every other element on the ui higher than this Three.js DOM element.

That is infact how the `Stats Element` (the one which shows you the current FPS ) is placed on top of the webGL element.

**Update 1:**

If you look at the DOM or the threejs implementation of [WebGLRenderer](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js)  you will find ,it creates  a canvas element if it doesn't finds one. so in  your CSS you can set the z-index property of this element in negative to achieve your desired result

**Update 2:**
Changing material color:

you can initialize the color in threejs like this.

```
var desiredColor= new THREE.Color( 0xff0000 );
```

or

```
var desiredColor= new THREE.Color("rgb(255,0,0)");
```

official documentation [here](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Color)

then you just need to set  this color in the material's color property by just removing the following lines of code from the `render` function

```
color = bird.material.color;
color.r = color.g = color.b = ( 500 - bird.position.z ) / 1000;
```

and adding these lines instead.

```
bird.material.color= desiredColor; // in this case it will change all bird's color to red
```

Comment: hi.. thnks a lot.. can you also suggest a way to chng the color of the birds??

Comment: @KrishnaKhowal: if this solved your problem then, mark the answer as accepted and close the question

Answer (score 0):

its pretty easy to change colors to a material...
In render function just remove the below mentioned line...you can view random colors of birds..

```
color = bird.material.color;
color.r = color.g = color.b = ( 500 - bird.position.z ) / 1000;
```

the below line coding does the material random coloring... {color:Math.random() *0xffffff} gives random color to all birds... just change it as color:0x000000... u can view the bird color in black....

```
bird = birds[ i ] = new THREE.Mesh( new Bird(), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color:Math.random() * 0xffffff, side: THREE.DoubleSide } ) );
```

it will do the trick...